# PhpStorm: {Model} and HasTimestamps define the same property timestamps (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

PhpStorm version 2020.3 shows an error on `$timestamps` property in my Laravel model:

> {Model} and HasTimestamps define the same property timestamps

[image]

Comment: I think timestamps is a reserved keyword, You can't use it.

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun, in Laravel, public $timestamps variable in models tells that the model does not use created_at and updated_at - by default $timestamps = true. It is not a reserved keyword. I have the same issue and I think this is a bug in the last update and it gets matched with vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasTimestamps.php. However, it is not a blocker and all work as normal, in my case at least.

Comment: @ Strabek, Yeap you are right. Maybe it's a phpstorm bug.

Answer (score 44):

This is a bug and it's introduced in the [new](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56143) version of PhpStorm.

It's not possible to disable the warning since it's an annotator inspection. I also don't recommend changing your code for the sole purpose of fixing this warning since it's an IDE bug and will be addressed in their [next](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56143#focus=Comments-27-4560769.0-0) patch. If it's not really causing any breaking side effects, just wait until the patch is released!

---

#### Update

This bug has been fixed in PhpStorm [2020.3.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/12/phpstorm-2020-3-1-is-released/).

Comment: first time I manage to solve a problem by doing nothing, without spending hours looking for an answer! Thanks

Comment: PHPStorm is absolutely unbeatable in terms of intellisense and refactoring power, but it really makes me feel chained when it seems like every update introduces a bug like this that I have to wait for them to fix :(

Answer (score 10):

It seems like a PHPStorm bug.

If it bothers you, you can change `public $timestamps = false;` to

```
public function usesTimestamps() : bool{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would argue its not a PHP storm issue but a Laravel issue.  https://www.php.net/traits#language.oop5.interfaces.examples.ex1
You solution is probably valid though if the rest of the code dont access the property directly, since its declared public. Reassigning the property in a construct feel worse but is perhaps more solid?

Comment: @hatef is right, you shouldn't be changing your code, I just find it very annoying visually, I actually had to revert since my current xdebug version is not compatible with that PHPStorm release, and #at#Johan I'm not sure I just again did it because of the warning but has no real benefit, and also I do not see any "super" negative since the method is public

Comment: @Johan, it has to be a PhpStorm bug. In PHP, a class can not use a trait and override a property from that trait. But this is not the case, the one overriding is a subclass of the class using the trait. And that's completely legal.

Comment: @dRamentol Thanks for straightening that out. If an update fixes the issue that's an indication of who’s to blame :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a PhpStorm bug, I fixed with define as property on class phpdoc.

Like this:

[image: Php storm bug fix]

Also you can update your PhpStorm.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed on PHPStrom 2020.3.1 Preview
https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2020/12/phpstorm-2020-3-1-preview/

Answer (score -2):

Very simple, add (bool) or (boolean), look: public $timestamps = (boolean) false;

Comment: produces error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in ...